# Why a change in my DotNetNuke module does not reflect at the client immediately?

Tags: kendo-grid, dotnetnuke

When I make a change in my DotNetNuke Module the clients can't see the change immediately.
For example: I'm using a KendoGrid and if I make a change the column's order, it doesn't reflect in clients immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using resources (.js or .css) for your code, you need to modify the names of these files. You can for example add a number at the end of each file. This will force browser to reload your sources every time you make a change.

Comment: and depending on your particular setup, some servers also do caching of 'static' files (i.e. .css, .js)